# Order by depending on 2 column values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query which returns the output as below,

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.rev_date ,fruitname,
 fruit_id , primary_fruit_id
FROM fruits a, fruit_lookup s,fruit_reference r 
WHERE a.id = s.id(+) 
 and primary_fruit_id = r.fruit_id(+) 
AND (fruit_id = 24 or fruit_id = 0) 
ORDER BY fruit_id desc, a.rev_date desc
```

How to handle this such that I still get the desired output where when both the id and primary id are same show them first? any idea is appreciated. I tried doing union etc but not getting the desired o/p. The order by fruit_id desc is not right as this is not ordering in the correct manner.thanks

```
 NAME       FRUIT_ID    PRIMARY_FRUIT_ID
--------------------------------------
apple       24          24
orange      24          12   
pear        24           7
apple       24          24
kiwi        24           6
apple       24          24   
apple       24          24
melon       24           2  
grape        0          90
banana       0          45
carrot       0          30
```

Desired output

```
NAME    FRUIT_ID    PRIMARY_FRUIT_ID
--------------------------------------
apple       24          24    
apple       24          24
apple       24          24    
apple       24          24
kiwi        24           6    
orange      24          12   
melon       24           2      
pear        24           7
grape        0          90
banana       0          45
carrot       0          30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate a value just to sort on based on the condition you want.

```
ORDER BY fruit_id desc,
         a.rev_date desc,
         case when fruit_id = primary_fruit_id then 0 else 1 end
```

You don't show the date field in your sample outputs, so I don't know how that date segments the output. I'm guessing that the date is more relevant than the "same key value" but you can place it wherever gives you the effect you want.

```
ORDER BY fruit_id desc,
         case when fruit_id = primary_fruit_id then 0 else 1 end,
         a.rev_date desc

ORDER BY case when fruit_id = primary_fruit_id then 0 else 1 end,
         fruit_id desc,
         a.rev_date desc
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this works. I have another condition where if columnA = 'Y' then that row needs to be on the very top of the result set. any idea how this can be achieved? thanks

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out! thanks a lot, this helped me learn how to order based on column values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY fruit_id desc, abs(fruit_id-PRIMARY_FRUIT_ID) asc
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.