# Order by query results in specific row positions

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is an extension to a previous quesiton, [Order by depending on 2 col values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951746/order-by-depending-on-2-column-values/28956059) I have a query which returns the output as below,

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.rev_date ,fruitname,
 fruit_id , primary_fruit_id
FROM fruits a, fruit_lookup s,fruit_reference r 
WHERE a.id = s.id(+) 
 and primary_fruit_id = r.fruit_id(+) 
AND (fruit_id = 24 or fruit_id = 0) 
ORDER BY case when fruit_id = primary_fruit_id then 0 else 1 end,
         fruit_id desc,
         a.rev_date desc
```

How to handle this such that I get the desired output in the below fashion. So, where ever the fruit_id is 0, those rows need to go in the 2nd  and the 5th row in the result set of say 10 rows. If totals results are around 50, each page will have 10 results, and in 2nd and the 5th position I need to get the output as below. Hope this makes sense. Any ideas are appreciated. thx

```
 NAME       FRUIT_ID    PRIMARY_FRUIT_ID
--------------------------------------
apple       24          24
apple       24          24
apple       24          24   
apple       24          24
orange      24          12   
pear        24           7
kiwi        24           6
melon       24           2  
grape        0          90
banana       0          45
carrot       0          30    
Desired output
NAME    FRUIT_ID    PRIMARY_FRUIT_ID
--------------------------------------
apple       24          24   
grape        0          90 
apple       24          24
apple       24          24 
banana       0          45   
apple       24          24
kiwi        24           6    
orange      24          12   
melon       24           2      
pear        24           7
carrot       0          30
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much more complicated question than your previous, so answer is somewhat complicated too. 
Here is something what I managed to do:

```
with t as (
  select x.*,
      row_number() over (
        partition by fid order by decode(fid , pfid, 1, 2), rd desc) rbr
    from (
      select distinct a.rev_date rd, s.fruitname fn, 
          a.fruit_id fid, primary_fruit_id pfid
        from fruits a left join fruit_lookup s on a.id = s.id
          left join fruit_reference r 
            on primary_fruit_id = r.fruit_id and r.fruit_id in (0, 24) ) x),
ca as (select count(1) cnt from t),
cx as (
  select row_number() over (partition by cwm order by lvl) rn, cwm, lvl 
    from (
      select level lvl, case when mod(level, 10) in (2, 5) then 0 else 24 end cwm 
        from ca connect by level <= cnt*5))
select rd, fn, fid, pfid 
  from t join cx on cx.rn = t.rbr and cx.cwm = t.fid
  order by lvl
```

You did not provide data structures and sample rows, so I tried to reproduce them to get original input, here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9762/1) with data and query.

Subquery `cx` generates numbers, according to your rules, then these numbers are assigned to your original query 
and final select sorts data using these numbers.
The general logic is: insert rows with fruit_id=0 numbered as 2, 5, 12, 15, 22...  between other rows.